# Perl String - Substitute Multiple Characters

Tags: perl

I couldn't figure out how to change from **/usr/lib** to **/synopsys/vcs/lib/** by only using **$mypath=~s/.....;**
is there anyway to do it?

````
$mypath = "/usr/lib";
$mypath =~ s/usr/synopsys/lib//g;

print "$mypath\n";```
````

Comment: My lecturer gave me this question where i had to fill in the blank which is ```$mypath =~ s/____________;``` , but i couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is a special character since it's being used as the delimiter. If therefore needs to be escaped.

```perl
$mypath =~ s/\/usr\/lib/\/synopsys\/vcs\/lib\//;
```

However, using an alternative delimiter means we wouldn't need all those escapes.

```perl
$mypath =~ s{/usr/lib}{/synopsys/vcs/lib/};
```

That replaces the first instance of `/usr/lib` *contained in the string*. If you want to replace `/usr/lib` when it's the entirety of the string, I'd use

```perl
$mypath = "/synopsys/vcs/lib/" if $mypath eq "/usr/lib";
```

Answer (score 1):

the regex replace works like `s/match this / replace with this /`
In perl you need to escape the forward slash / with a back slash `\`
then use parentheses to capture `usr\/` into `$1`
So for your example:

```
$mypath =~ s/(usr\/)/$1synopsys\//;
```

Comment: You could use a different character as the delimiter so you don't have to escape the /  like s#(usr/)#$1synopsys/#